# For which $n$ can $\{1,2,...,n\}$ be rearranged so that the sum of each two adjacent terms is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

For which numbers $n$ can the sequence $1$ to $n$ be rearranged such that each pair of consecutive terms adds up to a perfect square?

Can this be done on the set of natural numbers as well? Integers? Rationals?

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150161/ordering-117-by-perfect-square-pairs).

Comment: Could you put these numbers on a circle? ( I mean can these numbers be put so that the sum of the first and last numbers are a square as well?)

Comment: Am I the only one who finds the animation in the graphic annoying?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII My understanding of the question was that the pairs would work like this, starting from the blue end: [1,3],[3,13],[13,23],[23,26], etc., so that the second number in pair N is the first number in pair N+1.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169177/arrangement-of-integers-in-a-row-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-numbers?lq=1) or duplicate

Comment: it is conjectured that there is a solution for all $n>24$

Comment: @nhgrif: I see.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I think the graphic helped the post get more than 10 upvotes, while [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169177/arrangement-of-integers-in-a-row-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-numbers) from ***exactly*** a year ago and which is very similar got only 3. I guess some readers are quite visual. :)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A090460

Comment: Speaking of all natural numbers, see https://oeis.org/A034175.

Comment: The animated part seems quite  pointless as it is it seems it illustrates strictly nothing. Would it run through the pairs and display the sum there'd be some point to it.

Comment: @MXYMXY: Yes, and there are $57$ different ways to put them in such a circle. Kindly see answer below.

Answer (score 8):

(*Just to summarize things so people don't have to jump from MSE, MO, OEIS, SO.*)

This is a rather interesting question, but there are two previous MSE posts that have already covered it. [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169177/arrangement-of-integers-in-a-row-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-numbers?lq=1) (MSE) asks for which $n$ we can arrange {$1,2,\dots n$} so that the sum $S^k$ of every two adjacent numbers is a square (or $k=2$). A commenter pointed [A090461](http://oeis.org/A090461) hence,

$$n = 15,16,17,23,25,26,27,\dots,\infty$$

so it is conjectured for all $n>24$. That, in turn, was inspired by [Post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number) (MSE) which was the general case, but focused on sums $S^k$ for $k>2$. For $k=3$, the OP gave an example as $n=305$.

[Post 3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/199846/12905) (MO) gives an example for $k=4$ as $n=9641$. It was also a *cyclic arrangement*; that is, the first and last entries also have a sum $S^k$.

**P.S.** Re MYXMYX's question here if there is a cyclic arrangement for $n=35$ for squares, MJD found there are a whopping $17175$ [possible arrangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number#comment2385534_1168983), <strike>so chances are good</strike>. By the update below, OEIS says there are $57$ ways to do it.)

Comment: (*Update.*) Let $n$ have all adjacent pair-sums as $S^2$. Then the number of *circular arrangements* $m_c$ starting with $n=32$ is given by [A071984](http://oeis.org/A071984) as,  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline n&\text{# of}\;m_c\\32&1\\33&1\\34&11\\35&57\\
\hline\end{array}$$