# numberphiles's square-sum problem

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY

I do not know any details or anything, but it seems like this very interesting conjecture doesn't have a name or something, I could not search it. Does anyone know more about this problem?

For those who didn't watch the video, here is the conjecture.

"For large enough $N$, there exists some permutation of $\{1,2,...,N\}$ such that for every pair of adjacent number, the sum is always square."

My guess is that they discovered this problem themselves, but it's sure interesting!

I'm asking if this problem has a name, or was noted by a mathematical organization or by a journal, or mathematician. It seems like since there is OEIS dedicated to such possible N there must be some recognition of this problem.

Comment: This is sequence [A090461](https://oeis.org/A090461).

Comment: @JackM this question is related but different. The link you posted concerns the existence of at least one N for each power. This question suggests that for squares in particular an arrangement can be found for any sufficiently large N.

Comment: @JackM each of these questions are different. They shouldn’t be marked as duplicates just because they are related.

Comment: Tito Piezas summarized all the duplicates of this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1677260/113376