# What is the name of the conjecture related to what Matt Parker has called "The Square-Sum Problem"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, conjectures

I read a book called *Things to Make and Do in the Fourth Dimension*, written by Australian mathe-matician and comedian, Matt Parker. In one part of the book, I remember him explaining about a conjecture such that for all $n\geqslant 89$, you can arrange the elements of the set $\{1, 2,\ldots,n\}$ in a certain way where each adjacent pair of elements sums to a squared number. For example, let $n = 17$. Al-though $17<89$, below is a good example to demonstrate what I mean:

We have the set $\{1, 2, 3,\ldots, 17\}$ which can also be written as $\mathbb{N}_{\leqslant 17}$. How can we order each number in a certain way such that every adjacent pair of numbers in the ordered sequence add up to a squa-red number? Well, we order it like so:

> > Let $S_{17} = [\ldots]$ be our sequence that orders the elements from $\{1, 2, 3,\ldots, 17\}$ in a certain way as mentioned in the foregoing then, $$S_{17} := \big[17, 8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9, 16\big].$$ Here, $17 + 8 = 5^2$, $8 + 1 = 3^2$, $1 + 15 = 4^2,\ldots$

The sequence in the sandbox above is a special case where it has $17$ elements and *begins* with $17$. Take the sequence $S_{16}$ then this sequence *ends* with $16$. In fact, it is exactly the same as $S_{17}$ except it does not start from $17$, but $8$ instead. However, the sequence $S_{18}$ does not exist, and there are many sequences with this property that do not exist. The conjecture is interesting because if true, it will prove that there are only *finitely*  many sequences $S_n$ that do not exist, also proving the contrapo-sitive.

I did some research and it seems like this is true for $89\leqslant n \leqslant 300$ thus far, but I do not know the name of this conjecture. Does it even *have* a name? I also haven’t stumbled across any attempts of *proving* this conjecture. Can it be done? I guess that is two questions, then.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks @GTonyJacobs for the edit :)

Comment: Related but different question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number

Comment: @PatrickStevens thank you very much for that :) $\dots$ However do you know the name of this conjecture by any chance?

Comment: The meaning of the title is impossible to decipher.

Comment: @Did *there exists infinitely many of the special sequences that orders elements from $1$ to $n$, for all $n\geqslant 89$*. These special sequences, denoted as $S_n$, are defined above.

Comment: If you say so. Anyway, the title does not say that (actually it is difficult to know what the title is really saying). Please modify.

Comment: @Did ok, I will. Thank u for telling me, so I know that maybe other users may not understand the title :)

Comment: I'm with @Did. However, if the title is meant as a negative advertisement, it worked on me :)

Comment: @yo' so you understand the title? I just don't want to make it too wordy, is all. But I guess that if nobody understands it, what's the point anyway?

Comment: @user477343 If you really want to know my frank opinion: The title is  stupid. It uses non-standard notation ($\mathop{\exists}\limits^\infty$), it has the operators in the wrong order (I suppose you wanna say "for all $n\geq89$ there exist infinitely many") and it contains undefined symbols ($S_n$) that have many meanings in many contexts, and also, it's a title that uses math notation in a place where none is appropriate. Actually, why do you write $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq89}$ for something as simple as $\forall n\geq89$?

Comment: "there are many sequences with this property that do not exist." Sorry, but that's a self-contradicting sentence. What do you really mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I figured from context that they meant "there are many numbers $n$ such that it is not possible to arrange the numbers from $1$ to $n$ in a list with pairs of adjacent numbers summing to a square". (In fact, it seems [there are 20 such numbers](https://oeis.org/A078107).)

Comment: @Mark, you may be right, but I'd like to see OP edit the body of the question into something that makes sense.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676413/for-which-n-can-1-2-n-be-rearranged-so-that-the-sum-of-each-two-adja is very closely related, and a number of other questions were asked on MSE a while back.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you for the edit :)

Answer (score 3):

On the [OEIS sequence for counterexamples](https://oeis.org/A078107), [R.K.Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_K._Guy) claims that "the problem originated (for n = 15) with [Bernardo Recamán Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235016/bernardo-recam%C3%A1n-santos) of Colombia.", but does not give a name for the problem.

On [a Numberphile episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY), Matt Parker himself has given this problem the name "The Square-Sum Problem".

I have not evaluated the proof myself, but there is what amounts to a program and description (a preprint?) purporting to prove this conjecture at [this mersenneforum post](http://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=478035#post478035) (and the preceding posts help for context) by [Robert Gerbicz](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgerbicz/).

For the same problem but requiring the numbers to make a loop (so that the first and last numbers sum to a square as well), the numbers of solutions for small $n$ are documented in [OEIS A071984](https://oeis.org/A071984). Guy attributed that version of the problem to Joe Kisenwether. In fact, the above post by Robert Gerbicz handles the corresponding conjecture for loops (loops exist for all $n\ge32$) as well.

There is a related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number) and [corresponding MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199677/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number) about perfect powers with or without loops in more generality.