# Integers and Number-theory

Tags: number-theory, integers

The positive integers from $1$ to $n$ (where $n>1$) are arranged in a line such that
the sum of any two adjacent numbers is a square. What is the minimum value
of $n$?

Comment: Is this your own question or you heard it somewhere because n=1

Comment: I found one for n=15 but don't know about maximum value of n $8,1,15,10,6,3,13,12,4,5,11,14,2,7,9$ and this one for n=32 on internet $1,8,28,21,4,32,17 ,19$,$30,6,3, 13,12,24,25,11,5,31$,$18,7,29,20 ,16,9,27,22,14,2,23,26,10,15$

Comment: @LoveInvariants, it is lovely to get it for two numbers

Comment: @Satish Ramanathan-Thx

Answer (score 5):

It is conjectured that there is not a *maximum* value of $n$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637546/what-is-the-name-of-the-conjecture-related-to-what-matt-parker-has-called-the-s). It is a question of mine regarding exactly this, and today, it still remains an open problem such that most people I know refer to it as the "Square-Sum Problem."

An Australian mathematician by the name of Matt Parker perhaps introduced this problem or popularised it in one of his books, *Things to Make and Do in the Fourth Dimension* $(2014)$. In the book, he conjectured that there always exists such a sequence for $n > 89$, and then $n > 91$.

However, in a [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A) YouTube video, Matt Parker and his friend talks about how they tested this conjecture for more values, and as far as I know, the conjecture is true thus far and we now want to test for values $n > 300$.

The video has two parts, [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A) and [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_ph5djCCnM).

---

The *minimum* value of $n$ is definitely not $2$, as $1+2=3\neq k^2$ for an integer $k$. I believe the minimum value is $15$, but I have to go through the book again. In the meantime, I will attempt to write a program...

**Edit:** Notice that the $15$-length sequence (as pointed out by @LoveInvariants), $$8,1,15,10,6,3,13,12,4,5,11,14,2,7,9$$ has a particular method of being found. You start with all the number from $1$ to $15$. Then, you start your sequence with $1$. Now, looking at the remainding numbers, find the *highest* number out of those such that when you add $1$ to it, the result is a square number. The answer, is $15$. Now with your new remainding numbers, find the *lowest* number out of those such that when you add $15$ to it, the result is a square number. Next, find the *highest*, then the *lowest*, and continue. You should have one number left: $8$, and now, all is left is to put the $8$ at the beginning of the sequence before $1$. As far as I have tested in the last two months or so, this is the *only* sequence that can be generated using this specific method.

This might contribute to why $15$ might be the minimum value for $n$.

---

**Update:**

Ok the coding finished and I left the program running overnight. After fixing a couple of errors in the morning, it turns out $15$ is in fact the minimum value of $n$.

Comment: Doesn't the method from the video (succesively setting up a graph and connecting numbers with an edge that sum to a square number) show that $n=15$ is the minimum value because this is the smallest $n$ where you have a Hamiltoninan path?

Comment: @Janik Well if that is the case, then it is. I am no expert in Hamiltonian paths and such kinds of networks (or graphs). My coding hasn't finished yet, but soon, I will be able to check by brute-force.

Comment: Thank You all for the solutions.  Now, I understand the problem very well.   Greatly appreciated!   :-)