# Generalisation of this circular arrangement of numbers from $1$ to $32$ with two adjacent numbers being perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, puzzle, square-numbers

I got this interesting arrangement of numbers from $1$ to $32$ in a group in Facebook-
[image]

This being an interesting property to look at, I was trying to figure out whether $32$ is something special, or does this hold for other numbers as well. So, let's say, we want to construct one such circle for a general $n$. My idea was to take any $m\in \mathbb N_n=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ and find two different integers $x,y\in\mathbb N_n$ so that both $(m+x)$ and $(m+y)$ are perfect squares. Then, we need to find $x^\prime, y^\prime\in \mathbb N_n$ different from $x$, $y$ and $m$ such that both $(x+x^\prime)$ and $(y+y^\prime)$ are perfect squares. Then, we can continue in this manner.

Now, for any two $a,b\in \mathbb N_n$, we have $2\leq a+b\leq 2n$. So, for our given $m$, when we are looking for the mentioned $x$ and $y$, we only need to check through all the perfect squares in the interval $[m,2n]$. So, to reduce our work, we can take our initial choice $m$ to be equal to $n$.

But, now comes the main problem. Let's say, we want to work it out for $\mathbb N_{33}$. So, let's say, our initial $m$ is $33$. The values of $x$ and $y$ can be from the set $\{3,16,31\}$. The question is, which two of these three to choose so that eventually we don't run into a repitition. Note that, in the $\mathbb N_{32}$ case (which is the one in the diagram), taking $m=32$ leaves us with an advantage of having only two choices $4$ and $17$. But, in the next step, for finding the appropriate $x^\prime$ for $x=4$, we have the choices $\{5,12,21\}$ (since $32$ is already taken). The given diagram uses $x^\prime =21$. I tried using $x^\prime =5$ and then using values of my choice, but soon ran into an unavoidable repitition.

So, is there a way to make more circles with other values of $n$, or does $32$ have some profound property which makes it the only possible choice for $n$? I thought, maybe $32$ being a power of $2$ has to do something with it. So, I tried using $n=2,4,8,16$. But, these are trivially NOT solutions since there aren't enough perfect squares in $[n,2n]$ for these values of $n$. Note that this "not enough squares" angle immediately gives a lower bound of $n\geq 19$ by trial and error. Peter Taylor pointed out in the MathOverflow post that this "not enough squares" argument also rules out $n\le 30$ since $18$ is always a vertex of degree $1$ otherwise. So, we have a lower bound of $n\ge 31$. Also, I was too lazy to even attempt $n=64$.

So, is this case a rare coincidence, or can we have other values of $n$ satisfying this property as well? If there are other values, what family do they belong to? Also, for any case, is that arrangement unique?

**Edit:** I got one interesting answer that uses graph theory. But, that has a computer program to check that it holds for all $100\geq n\geq 32$. However, I want more "mathy" arguments. I want to see why this happens instead of to only confirm that it happens. I want to know whether it happens for all $n$ or whether there are cases where it breaks down. Please consider these questions as well.

Also, [here's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408235/generalisation-of-this-circular-arrangement-of-numbers-from-1-to-32-with-two) the MathOverflow post of the same question. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/a/408383/311366) answer gives two sequences in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, [A071983](http://oeis.org/A071983) and [A071984](http://oeis.org/A071984) which seems somewhat relevant.

Comment: Is your question how this arrangement has been found and whether it is essentially unique ?

Comment: One way to solve this is to construct a graph with $N$ vertices where two vertices are adjacent if and only if the number of the vertices sum up to a perfect square. The object is then to find a hamilton cycle in this graph.

Comment: This is a nice problem. Similar questions have been asked for a while, some information can be found e.g. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676413/for-which-n-can-1-2-n-be-rearranged-so-that-the-sum-of-each-two-adja?noredirect=1&lq=1)  by Tito Piezas III

Comment: The below answer demonstrates that the number of edges is small enough that the determination of a hamilton cycle is still feasible for a surprising large number of vertices. More interesting however would be a specific method that works for every $N\ge 32$ , is such a method known ?

Comment: This comment seems to mostly explain things: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number#comment2382827_1168983

Comment: @Peter my question is basically how we can generalise it. Take what you want from that.

Comment: @user376343 I saw a similar question, but that (and this one as well) deals with numbers arranged in a row, mine deals with a circle.

Comment: @DanielV yes, that's a good comment. How do you share comments by the way?

Comment: @Asher2211 what change did you make in the MathJax code for formatting the picture?

Comment: @SayanDutta I saw the problem in January 5 2021 [here](https://brainly.in/question/32595343) As for the linked answer by Tito Piezas III ... I was thinking of the comment below his answer.

Comment: This is neat! +1.

Comment: @JairTaylor so is your work on group laws and hypergraph colourings! Didn't understand much (being just an undergrad) to be honest, but still, found it quite interesting :)

Comment: @SayanDutta Oh, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to construct a graph $G(n)$ on the vertex set $V = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, where an edge is drawn between vertices $v_i \ne v_j$ if and only if $v_i + v_j = k^2$ for some integer $k$.  Then we search for a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.  If such a cycle exists for a given $n$, then the integers from $1$ to $n$ can be arranged without repetition in such a circle as shown in your image.

This is easily done in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
G[n_] := AdjacencyGraph[
           Table[Boole@And[IntegerQ[Sqrt[i + j]], i != j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

t = Select[Table[n, {n, 3, 100}], HamiltonianGraphQ[G[n]]]
FindHamiltonianCycle[G[#]]& /@ t
```

Then $t$ looks like this:

$$t = \{32, 33, 34, \ldots, 100 \}$$

This proves $n = 32$ is the smallest such graph that admits a circle of the desired type, and suggests but does not prove that for every $n > 32$, a circle of the desired type exists.

For instance, $n = 100$ gives the circle

$$\{1,80,89,11,70,30,91,9,72,28,53,47,74,7,93,51,49,32,68,13,87,34,66,15,85,59,41,40,81,19,17,83,61,60,84,37,27,54,46,75,6,94,50,71,10,90,31,69,12,88,33,67,14,86,35,65,16,20,29,52,92,8,73,48,96,4,77,23,98,2,79,21,100,44,56,25,39,42,58,63,18,82,62,38,43,57,64,36,45,55,26,95,5,76,24,97,3,78,22,99\}.$$

Comment: This observation is quite nice! (+1) But we still haven't proved anything. Do you know of any tests to check the existence of Hamiltonian cycles in a graph? I don't think I know any such test :(

Comment: Where did you run that program? Can you maybe add a link please....

Comment: Are these circles unique for a given $n$? Or can we fix an $n$ and create some type of algebraic structure between all the possible circles?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $S_n$ is the number of distinct sums, of two distinct numbers, pertaining to $\mathbb{N}_n$ which are equal to squares, it follows by induction that $\{S_n\}$ is a monotonically non-decreasing sequence. Indeed,

$$ S_{n} = S_{n-1} + T_n ~~~(n \geq 2)$$

where $S_1 = 0$, and $T_n$ is the number of squares between $n+1$ and $2n-1$ (the range of the sums between the new element $n$ and all numbers in the previous set $\mathbb{N}_{n-1}$). Note that these cyclic sequences of $n$ integers are made of $n$ distinct pairs of numbers which sum up to a square. Therefore, $S_n \geq n$ is a necessary condition for the existence of such cycles.

Running a simple code in Sage:

```
S = [0]
for n in [2..100]:
   S.append(S[-1] + len([i for i in [n+1..2*n-1] if is_square(i) == True]))
```

I did find:

$$ \{S_n\} = \{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, \ldots\}$$

which in a quick search had an match with [OEIS:A176615](https://oeis.org/A176615), defined by the same problem in terms of graph theory. It seems that $S_n \geq n$ when $n \geq 15$. This is a quite awful lower bound, because the constraint in terms of $S_n$ isn't very tight. Although this isn't a answer to the general question, I've thought it would be a good idea to expose this result here, at least as a first attempt to make some sense of the confirmed lower bound at $n = 32$.

Comment: I see... Thanks for the answer (+1) But, this lower bound doesn't really add anything. I already got a lower bound of $n\geq 19$ as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry, my bad, I didn't read properly your post. I'll seek for a more useful result, in order to improve the remark.