# $1-8-28-21-4-32-17-19-30-6-3-13-12-24-25-11-5-31-18-7-29-20-16-9-27-22-14-2-23-26-10-15-1$ - amazing circle

Tags: circles, square-numbers, pattern-recognition

I found an amazing circle while surfing on the internet.(I will call this circle a 32-AC.) It is a circle with 32 numbers with no numbers written twice. Also, the sum of any two adjacent numbers is a square number. I will just write it in a row.

$\displaystyle 1-8-28-21-4-32-17-19-30-6-3-13-12-24-25-11-5-31-18-7-29-20-16-9-27-22-14-2-23-26-10-15-1$

You can try adding any adjacent two numbers and check that the result is square number.

> $9-36-49-25-36-49-36-49-36-9-16-25-36-49-36-16-36-49-25-36-49-36-25-36-49-36-16-25-49-36-25-16$

Maybe many people will know this circle, but my question is that "Is a 32-AC a smallest AC?", "Is there any n-AC such that n $\neq$ 32?", and "What is the pattern in the n-AC?".

If you have found any n-AC or have answered my question above, please answer it.

The n-AC definition were these.

(1)The n-AC should contain all the number 1~n only once.

(2)The sum of the two adjacent number should be a square number.

Comment: Why not to write any number in the first place and keep adding numbers to make the sum of this new entry and the previous one a square?

Comment: What about $1-8-1$ ? It is a $3-AC$, as you call it...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Oh, should my n-AC definition modified?
$$
\text{The n-AC definition were these.}
\ \\
(1) \text{The n-AC should contain all the number 1~n only once.}
(2) \text{The sum of the two adjacent number should be a square number.}
$$

Comment: @Math Indeed, you should change the definition in your question then.

Comment: Duplicate of [Generalisation of this circular arrangement of numbers from $1$ to $32$ with two adjacent numbers being perfect squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289064/generalisation-of-this-circular-arrangement-of-numbers-from-1-to-32-with-two), and also of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4291276/1508), both posted in the last few days.